# If Loop not working in for loop windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am having trouble getting the desired code to work properly.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set /a n1 = 5

for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (

if !x! lss !n1! (
echo %%x
PAUSE )
)
```

My output is attached: [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxFta.png)

[image]

My desired output is to obviously not output after reaching 5 in the for loop. Can anyone clarify why this is occurring?

Comment: Two things 1st while set /a allows spaces around the equal sign, it's a bad habit. -> `set /a "n1=5"`. 2nd you compare `!x!` an unassgned variable instead of `%%x`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I understand now and have it working. First day of batch programming. :/

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)